# Not setting an PHP array value inside a SQL query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm a beginner in Laravel. I have faced a issue in using a PHP array value inside a SQL query statement. 
I have a array `$waypoints` and it contains names of cities. And `var_dump($waypoints)` looks like follows.

```
array (size=4)
0 => string 'Paris' (length=5) 
1 => string 'Moscow' (length=6) 
2 => string 'London' (length=6) 
3 => string 'New York' (length=8)
```

And I am trying to find the corresponding `id`of a city by executing a SQL query. The code is as follow.

```
    $cityname = $waypoints[2];

    $city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "$cityname%")->firstOrFail();
```

This query does not get executed.

`var_dump($city)` is like this.

```
string 'select * from 'cities' where 'name' LIKE ? ' (length=42)
```

But if i set a string value to variable  `$cityname` manually(As example `$cityname = "London";`), it get executed.

I can't figure out the issue. Help Needed.

Comment: try this.. $city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', $cityname."%")->toSql();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do this

```
 $city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', $cityname."%")->firstOrFail();
```

**or**

```
 $city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "{$cityname}%")->firstOrFail();
```

**instead of**

```
 $city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "$cityname%")->firstOrFail();
```